# Display array after selecting with linq

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I'm trying to list all the words with 4 letters. But I'm not sure why it's not working. It will not display it.

This is the code:

```
    IEnumerable<string> query4 = words
       .Where(n => n.Length == 4)
       .Select(n => n);

    DisplayArray(query4);
```

This is my display method:

```
    private static void DisplayArray<T>(T[] array)
    {
        foreach (T item in array)
            Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
```

Comment: For starters `query4` isn't an array.  Either change your method to take `IEnumerable<T>` or use `ToArray`.

Comment: Thank's. I'am knew in linq. I thoat it beaves like an array

Comment: Nope, an array is a structure that contains a set of values where as a Linq query produces an `IEnumerable<T>` that only represents a sequence that is not set and you have to materialize it by using a `foreach` or `ToList` or `ToArray`.  Until then it doesn't actually do the filtering or projecting.  Also it will do the filtering and projecting each time you materialize it.  That's why you'll see a lot of Linq queries ending with a `ToList`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, according to your current code

```
  private static void DisplayArray<T>(T[] array)
```

wants array `T[]` but you provide just `IEnumerable<string>` and so you should have a *compile time error*. Change `T[]` to `IEnumrable<T>`:

```
  // you have no need in T[], IEnumerable<T> is quite enough
  private static void DisplayArray<T>(IEnumerable<T> array) {
    foreach (T item in array)
      Console.WriteLine(item);
  }
```

Finally (please, notice that `Select(n => n)` is *redundant* and can be dropped):

```
  DisplayArray(words.Where(n => n.Length == 4));
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It helped.

Comment: How can I make a method that will be good for array and for IEnumerable?

Comment: @sara: `T[]` (array) *implements* `IEnumerable<T>` so if you've implemented a method for `IEnumerable<T>` it will do for array `T[]`; the reverse is not true

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void DisplayArray(IEnumerable<string> array)
{
    foreach (string item in array)
       Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: It may appear that you *narrow down* `DisplayArray` method too hard; what if another Linq returns `IEnumerable<int>`?

Comment: as your provide IEnumerable<string> that why I use that. Thanks for your advice.